# Request Headers Causing ' Nock: No Match For Request'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-testing-library, nock

**Notable Tools I'm also using:** React; Express.JS as my APi.

**Output of Error:**

```
onsole.error
  pending mocks: ["GET http://localhost:5000/api/medias","GET http://localhost:5000/api/watching"]

  107 |         await waitForExpect(() => {
  108 |             if (!getMediasScope.isDone()) {
> 109 |                 console.error(
      |                         ^
  110 |                     "pending mocks: %j",
  111 |                     getMediasScope.pendingMocks()
  112 |                 );
```

**ComponentA**

```
useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchMedias(); //action creator, calls GET req of
                             //http://localhost:5000/api/medias
        props.fetchMediaWatchingByUser();  // action creator, calls  GET req of
                                           ///http://localhost:5000/api/watching

    }, []);


   .......
axiosConfig.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {

     const token = Cookies.get(ACCESS_TOKEN);
   
        if (token) {
            config.headers["authorization"] = token;
        }
        return config;
 (error) => {
        Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

**Test**

```
//Mock cookie, you need an access token cookie to enter this page
jest.mock("js-cookie", () => ({ get: () => "fr" }), {
    virtual: true,
});

beforeEach(async () => {
    app = render(
        <Root>
            <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/protected"]} initialIndex={0}>
                <Routes />
            </MemoryRouter>
        </Root>
    );
});


describe("When data is loaded ", () => {
    let accessTokenScope;
    let getMediasScope;
    let watchingScope;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const mockResponse = {
            medias: [
                {
                    title:"hi"
                },
            ],
        };

        getMediasScope = nock("http://localhost:5000")
            .get("/api/medias")
            .reply(200, mockResponse, {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            }).get("/api/watching")
            .reply(200, mockResponse, {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            });
    });

    test("Media sections exist", async () => {
        await waitForExpect(() => {
            if (!getMediasScope.isDone()) {
                console.error(
                    "pending mocks: %j",
                    getMediasScope.pendingMocks()
                );
            }
            expect(getMediasScope.isDone()).toBe(true);
        });

    }, 30000);
});
```

**Update:**

I pinpointed why the error occurs and tried to fix it. However, the error of 'pending mocks' still persists.

**The Cause of Error**

Request headers sent in  `http://localhost:5000/api/medias` is the reason why it's failing. By removing the **Authorization header**, the code above works.

[image]

**What I have tried to fix the error**

[Followed the documentation](https://github.com/nock/nock#specifying-headers) - thus, changing the nock requests above to:

```
 getMediasScope = nock("http://localhost:5000", {
            reqheaders: {
                Authorization: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9",
            },
        })
            
            .get("/api/medias")
            .reply(200, mockResponse, {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            })
            .get("/api/watching")
            .reply(200, watchingResponse, {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            });
```

**Using the debug that @Matt R.Wilson suggested gives me**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling debugging output from Nock? https://github.com/nock/nock#debugging It might shed some light on why request is not matching the Interceptor on `getMediasScope`.

Comment: @MattR.Wilson I took a quick peek at my request headers (added screenshots above) and it looks like by removing the 'Authorization Header' the /api/medias works! However, the request  headercookies are not being sent in both mock requests. I'll look  more on it tomorrow :)!

Comment: @MattR.Wilson Added the debug from the terminal and the cause of error! hopefully, it helps. I'm not sure why nock still can't intercept it.

Comment: The provided error you showed is not the debugging output. It's just the thrown error being logged. You should have much more verbose output. Either way, it seems the actual request being made is an `OPTIONS` request, not `GET` and does not include an `Authorization` header.

Comment: Thanks for the response @MattR.Wilson. I tried to debug it by running the command `SET DEBUG=nock.* npm run test` in my terminal; if I did it wrong, please let me know. Also, it looks like I'm getting the same error if I send the OPTIONS pre-flight first (screenshot): https://gyazo.com/0aad20ac032057b881cac03de1d83781  . However, if I send it without the GET requests, the pending mocks will pass but the test won't receive the data.

Comment: I'm lost on what exactly your code looks like at this point. Are you able to provide a small reproduction of this issue in full?

Comment: @MattR.Wilson Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the code due to the libraries being used. However, my current testing code is in this screenshot: https://gyazo.com/8ac719fd7190d3f96243a3690fd903fd  . After you mentioned that an OPTIONS request is being made - I added an `.intercept("/api/medias", "OPTIONS")` to my nock getters; which is shown in the screenshot. I included the  code where I sent my `authorization header` in the post, which I believe is the problem.